# what is the difference between var.op.name and var.name in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have one point confusing. Here is the example code:

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)       
for grad, var in grads_and_vars:        
    print(var.op.name)
```

the output is: `conv1/filt conv1/bias`

and when I change `var.op.name` into `var.name`

the output is: `conv1/filt:0 conv1/bias:0`

What is the difference between `var.op.name` and `var.name`? 
and what does `:0` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`op.name` is the name of the Operation, while `var.name` is the name of the Tensor. Operation is the thing that allocates memory, and produces outputs available on endpoints :0, :1, etc. Tensor is an output of an operation, so it corresponds to some endpoint. In this case `conv1/filt` is the Variable Operation that is in charge of the memory, and `conv1/filt:0` is the first endpoint of that operation. The practical difference is that `conv1/filt:0` is what you can fetch to get the value, ie `sess.run(["conv1/filt:0"])`, while you use use `conv1/filt` to get a hold of operation, ie `tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("conv1/filt")`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, OP is just added to initialize all variables. The :0 is just the first output, so if there was another conv1/filt it would be presented as conv1/filt:1.